# Pick one value out of a table in MS access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a program for my lab. Based on a salesordernumer (SO-nr) I need to find the corresponding part number out of a table in access and put it into a variable( Prob a string?). later I need to split the different parts from the partnumber but before that I need to get it out of the MS table. This is de code I use now but I get an error.

```
Private Sub BtnOphaal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOphaal.Click

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Dim Sonr As String

        Sonr = "SELECT *FROM prodvolg "
        Dim SQL As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sonr, conn)
        Dim DataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL)

        Dim datatabel As New DataTable("prodvolg")

        DataAdapter.Fill(datatabel)
        Dim queryString As String = "SELECT [pPart] AS Partnummer FROM [prodvolg] WHERE ([pSonr]='" & txtSOnummer.Text & "')"
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, conn)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            txtppart.Text = (reader.GetString(1))

        End While

        reader.Close()

    End If


End Sub
```

As you can see I'm just a beginning programmer.

The error is occuring at `txtppart.Text = (reader.GetString(1))` the error message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at school I learned programming at ADO system but the future seems to be oledb but I don't understand the OLEdb system good so far. If anyone could help me I would be so happy. 
The partnumber is could look like this: "CA-017630-6.35M-1/0-2"

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at index zero, not one. You have only one field returned by the query

```
txtppart.Text = (reader.GetString(0))
```

Also, keep in mind that GetString could fail if your row at index zero contains a null value.
If this is the case I suggest to check for null values with

```
txtppart.Text = IF(reader.IsDBNull(0), string.Empty, reader.GetString(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving just one field `pPart` with your SQL statement, so you'll have just one field on the DataReader. Try with `reader.GetString(0)`, because the arrays starts at index zero